# backgroundColor isn't doing anything?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to implement it on a website however for the life of me I can't get `backgroundColor` to do anything!

```
let col = document.getElementById('js');
col.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  col.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  console.log('wow');
});
```

I was using `getElementsByClassName` but for simplicities sake I thought I'd just change to `getElementById` to try and diagnose what's going on.

When I hover over the element I do see 'wow' in the console.

If I try and change to:

```
document.main.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

or something it throws me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at
>   HTMLHeadingElement.col.addEventListener (list-script.js:14)

I know this may be incredibly simple for some of you but I just need a leg up to get the ball rolling.

I just want to change the background of the element that I've assigned to `Id="js"`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<body class="container">
  <header>
    <div>
      <a class="header-l" href="./index.html"><img class="header-img" src="./img//arrow-left.png" alt="Lists Arrow"><h1 class="text-style">Lists</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-c"><h1 id="js">Shopping for lots of things</h1></div>
    <div>
      <a class="header-r" href=""><img class="header-img" src="./img/user.jpg" alt="User Picture"><h1 class="text-style">Username</h1></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="./list-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script> </script>  <!-- stops CSS transitions from firing on load -->
</body>
```

As you can see the Id is on the h1 tag. When I hover I see no errors but also no background change. I've tried removing   but no change.

Thanks!

Comment: document.main doesn't exist, try to use document.body to acces the <body> tag

Comment: use css `#js:hover { background-color : blue; }`

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: @PranavCBalan I want to change a specific child of the anchor tag that I want to hover over.

Comment: @Maxwell s.c I tried that but like my original code above I saw nothing but 'wow' in console and no backgroundColor change.

Comment: instead of `document.main` you can use `document.querySelector('body')` to change the properties of <body>

Comment: @Krishanu this code is intended to simply change the backgroundColor of col / element with the id of 'js'.

Comment: where is your script file place in html??

Comment: Just above </body>

Comment: I've added the html to the question.

Comment: that JavaScript code works. maybe you don't have an element with id `js`

Comment: see this https://jsbin.com/miyufatesu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I dont see any styles in your example, however it's possible that you have styles which are either floating the H1, or setting its line height to 0, or otherwise effecting the elements calculated height, which is what is used by the browser to "fill in" the background color. Your js looks fine.

Comment: You probably have an `!important` statement somewhere else in CSS

Comment: What is the browser you are checking this on?

Comment: Nope. No !important statement. Chrome.

Comment: I answered the question. Was a CSS issue. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: It is not a typographical error.  It is a CSS conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working fine in a code snippet. I copied your code word for word into this snippet.
Run this code snippet and see for yourself.

```js
let col = document.getElementById('js');

col.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  col.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  console.log('wow');
});
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <header>
    <div>
      <a class="header-l" href="./index.html"><img class="header-img" src="./img//arrow-left.png" alt="Lists Arrow"><h1 class="text-style">Lists</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-c"><h1 id="js">Shopping for lots of things</h1></div>
    <div>
      <a class="header-r" href=""><img class="header-img" src="./img/user.jpg" alt="User Picture"><h1 class="text-style">Username</h1></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="./list-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script> </script>  <!-- stops CSS transitions from firing on load -->
</body>
```

Comment: yeah there's nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

AHHHH Sorry all. My fault. The problem was in the CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(100deg, #acaecb 0%, white 80%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Once I targeted another element with Id='js' it worked.

Thanks for all your help and comments.

Comment: CSS conflicts like this are not always easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message, because there is not a "main" object in document.

What you need to do is use `document.body` and then it will work.

```js
let col = document.getElementById('js');
col.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  col.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});

document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <header>
    <div>
      <a class="header-l" href="./index.html"><img class="header-img" src="./img//arrow-left.png" alt="Lists Arrow"><h1 class="text-style">Lists</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-c">
      <h1 id="js">Shopping for lots of things</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="header-r" href=""><img class="header-img" src="./img/user.jpg" alt="User Picture"><h1 class="text-style">Username</h1></a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

so since you are using `getElementsByClassName` you'll need to loop over each element and apply style for each.

```js
let col = document.getElementsByClassName('js');


for (let i = 0; i< col.length; i++) {
  
  col[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  col[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  console.log('wow');
});
}
```

```html
<div class="js"> div one</div>
<div class="js">div two</div>
<div class="js">div two</div>
<div class="js">div two</div>
<div class="js">div two</div>
```